# Yield keyword behavior in C# 2.0

Tags: c#, yield

In a method I yield a custom object which I reuse. later for yielding again.

```
private IEnumerable<DistributorMonthlyComparisonData> ExtractMonthlyAggregate(String CSVFilepath)
{
    DistributorMonthlyComparisonData unitData = new DistributorMonthlyComparisonData();
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            if(something){
                // fill unitData
                }
            else{
                 yield return unitData;
                }
        }
}
```

In another object in my program I call said method in this way:

```
List<DistributorMonthlyComparisonData> distribList = new List<DistributorMonthlyComparisonData>();
foreach (DistributorMonthlyComparisonData result in ExtractMonthlyAggregate(percorso))
  {
    distribList.Add(result);
  }
```

If I don't create in the yielding method, after each yield, a new object

```
unitData = new DistributorMonthlyComparisonData();
```

All I get is a List of identical objects.

I am wondering: is this because unitData  is being passed as a reference and thus the List is merely a List of references to the same identical object? Creating a new unitData() every time changes the hash of the unitData object being passed?

Please enlighten me. :)

**EDIT** I am interested in *why* this is happening.
I used to think that the framework is supposed to do copy-on-write on objects, so basically yielding one object then modifying its properties and then yielding it again should result in two different objects being added to the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# has reference semantics for class types, so you are right about references being returned.

Sidenote about the rest:

`yield return`/`yield break` will continue the loop you place them in. Therefore, the code before your loop is only executed once before the loop is entered. You would have to `new` your returned objects *inside* the loop.

I.e., you would have to replace

```
DistributorMonthlyComparisonData unitData = new DistributorMonthlyComparisonData();
while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
    ...
```

with

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
    DistributorMonthlyComparisonData unitData = new DistributorMonthlyComparisonData();
    ...
```

Comment: Yes. The new DistributorMonthlyComparisonData(); is done right after the yield, inside the loop. What I am wondering, is why this happens.

Comment: While debugging I noticed that instantiating a new unitData just after yield is the same as doing it at the top of every iteration, since the code will continue after the yield. We are doing basically the same, just in different places. :) Thanks phresnel.

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering: is this because unitData is being passed as a reference and thus the List is merely a List of references to the same identical object?

Exactly.

> Creating a new unitData() every time changes the hash of the unitData object being passed?

That depends on DistributorMonthlyComparisonData's implementation of GetHashCode().

Comment: There is no implementation of GetHashCode(), DistributorMonthlyComparisonData is just a collection of properties.

Answer (score 1):

The object initialization will happen only once. The execution will resume from the while loop from the second iteration onwards. That's why the object collection has the same object instances.

Comment: Thanks Jose, I am a poor writer and I expressed myself badly.I'd like to inquire in why rather than how this happens. See the edit above!

Comment: http://codemine.net/post/2010/06/05/What-is-Yield-Keyword-in-C-do.aspx This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

> Creating a new unitData() every time changes the hash of the unitData object being passed?
>
> There is no implementation of GetHashCode(), DistributorMonthlyComparisonData is just a collection of properties.

The default implementation of `GetHashCode()` makes no guarantees about its return value. So, if you have no custom implementation for it, you should not have any expectations about it.

When you define equality for a type (by overriding `Equals`) you have to override `GetHashCode` as well, and guarantee that objects that compare equal have the same hash code.